# typescript get "typeof" Generic class inside type declaration

Tags: typescript, generics, mobx, mobx-state-tree

I'm trying to make a custom hook that gets 2 parameters:
1- a class that's actually is a mobx store
2- parameters of that class constructor
this hook is lookalike this in javascript:

```js
/**
 * @template T
 * @param {new() => T} Store 
 * @param {any[]} initializers
 * @returns {T} an instance of the Mobx store/viewModel
 */
export const useMobx = (Store, initializers) => {
    const vm = useLazyRef(() => new Store(...initializers));
    return vm.current;
};
```

I just trying to rewrite it in typescript but it gets really complicated and after a lots of searches I can make it like this:

```js
interface ClassWithConstructor<T>{
    new (name:string):T ;
}
type fnArgs<U,T extends ClassWithConstructor<U>> = ConstructorParameters<T> extends any[] ? ConstructorParameters<T> : never;
type UseMobxType = <U,T extends ClassWithConstructor<U>,>(Store: new(...args: fnArgs<U,T>) => U, initializers:fnArgs<U,T>) => U;
export const useMobx:UseMobxType = (Store, initializers) => {
    const vm = useLazyRef(() => new Store(...initializers));
    return vm.current;
};
```

it's works without any problem but usage was a little stupid:

```
useMobx<AppStatusListViewModel, typeof AppStatusListViewModel>(AppStatusListViewModel,["param1"]);
```

as you can see I have to pass 2 generic classes `AppStatusListViewModel` and  `typeof AppStatusListViewModel` and I am wondering is there any better solution to make it easier to use for example like this:

```
useMobx<AppStatusListViewModel>(AppStatusListViewModel,["param1"]);
```

or even this:

```
useMobx(AppStatusListViewModel,["param1"]);
```

for more info useLazyRef source:

```js
type initValFunctionType = ()=>any;
export const useLazyRef = (initValFunc:initValFunctionType) => {
    const ref:React.MutableRefObject<any> = useRef(null);
    if (ref.current === null) {
        ref.current = initValFunc();
    }
    return ref;
};
```

and consider AppStatusListViewModel is just a simple ES6 class:

```js
class AppStatusListViewModel{
  constructor(name:string){
    console.log(name);
  }
}
```

Comment: What is `useLazyRef` and what is `AppStatusListViewModel`?  Please provide a [mre] that clearly demonstrates the issue you are facing.  Ideally someone could paste the code into a standalone IDE like [The TypeScript Playground (link here!)](https://tsplay.dev/w8o8AW) and immediately get to work solving the problem without first needing to re-create it.  So there should be no pseudocode, typos, unrelated errors, or undeclared types or values.

Comment: If you can make the example self-contained then I think the solution will be straightforward.  It will look *something* like [this](https://tsplay.dev/WPZn5N), but I won't know for sure until I can reproduce the issue without unrelated errors.

Comment: i just add detail you say you need

Answer (score 1):

It seems you have over-complicated the type definitions for the custom hook.

The following type definitions should stand enough with proper type inferences & IDE intellisense.

```
import { useRef } from 'react'

/**
 * @param initValFunc class instantiator function
 */
export const useLazyRef = <T>(initValFunc: () => T) => {
    const ref = useRef<T | undefined>()
    if (ref.current === undefined) {
        ref.current = initValFunc()
    }
    return ref
}

type UseMobxType = <U, T>(
    Store: new (...args: T[]) => U,
    initializers?: T[]
) => U

export const useMobx: UseMobxType = (Store, initializers = []) => {
    const vm = useLazyRef(() => new Store(...initializers))
    return vm.current!
}
```

you can check for the result & do custom manipulations using the following sandbox:

https://codesandbox.io/s/usemobx-ww79oe